# Javascript: problems with the order of my index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, chart.js

I am working on Angular and i use Chart.js, to prepare my data for the chart, I rank them in a table template formated like this :

my_table[2014] [[01] = {array},[02] = {array},...,[12] = {array}]

my_table[2015] [[01] = {array},[02] = {array},[03] = {array}]

when i log this table with a console.log, the table is good , but when i do my populate code the order of my index changes automatically :

```
for(year in my_table){
        for(month in my_table[year]){
            labels_list.push(month+'/'+year);
            total_nb_order.push(my_table[year][month]["nb_orders"]);
            total_data.push(my_table[year][month]["amount_ttc"]);
            vegetal_data.push(my_table[year][month]["amount_ttc_vgt"]);
            manufacture_data.push(my_table[year][month]["amount_ttc_manu"]);
        }
    }
```

my chart is good but not in the right chronological order ... indexes out in this order : [10],[11],[12],[01],[02],[03],...

any idea to help me ? :p

Comment: Maybe some kind of sorting for your arrays might help. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Is your array composed by Arrays only or also generic objects? in such a case, you shouldn't be using **for .. in** (there are many topics in stackoverflow). That said, you should sort your array first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly, `0` is a prefix for `octal` numbers. Change your code to `my_table[2014] [[1] = {array},[2] = {array},...,[12] = {array}]`.

Comment: thank you, I really wanted to understand why my table was reorganized

Comment: You may add the zero as a comment, e.g.: `my_table[/*0*/1]` (january)